# echo variable in double quotes showes a syntax-error in IDE

Tags: php, variables, syntax-error, echo

I use for PHP-coding Aptana Studio.

The following line gives me a syntax-error in Aptana-Studio:

```
<?php 
   if(isset($GLOBALS['errorSaveProfile'])) echo "<p>$GLOBALS['errorSaveProfile']</p>";
?>
```

But i don't understand why?

Comment: Specifically in the linked question, [this answer `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13935532/541091)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use single quotes in double quotes for array keys: `echo "<p>$GLOBALS[errorSaveProfile]</p>";`

There are different correct ways:

```
print $_GLOBALS['errorSaveProfile'];
print 'something '.$_GLOBALS['errorSaveProfile'].' something';
print "something {$_GLOBALS['errorSaveProfile']} something";
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double and http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($GLOBALS['errorSaveProfile'])) {
echo "<p>$GLOBALS[errorSaveProfile]</p>";
}
```

Comment: A single line or inline if statement is legal.

Comment: You're right. I feel so dumb now.

Comment: No worries, I've made mistakes that make something like that look like an award winning speech :P

Answer (score 0):

try

```
echo "<p>"; echo $GLOBALS['errorSaveProfile']; echo "</p>";
```

Comment: That's very ugly code. Concatenation is better here instead of 3 echos on the same line.